# Need help making dropdown menu part of navbar

Tags: html, css

The thing that's causing the problem is that when I make the size of the window smaller (restore down), the 4th sub div of `class=Menu` is not behaving like the other 3 divs, which I gave 25% width each. Instead, it is overflowing horizontally and going past the body, header and footer.

```css
/*---------Dropdown----------*/
.Menu, .Menu ul {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
list-style: none;
  width:25%;

  }

  .Menu li {                      
width: 14.84em;
  }

  .Menu li ul {                   /*Hides dropdown*/
position: absolute;
left: -999em;
  }

  .Menu li:hover ul {             /*Makes the dropdown show on hover*/
left: auto;
  }

  .Menu a {                       /*Styles the links on menubar */
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  }

  .Menu a:hover {                 /*background color of links change on 
  hover*/
  background-color:  #dcefdc;
  }

  .Menu div a{
  padding-top:11px;
  }

  .Menu div a:hover{
   height:50px;
  }

  .liwidth{
  float:left;
  background-color:#4CAF50 ;
  height:50px;
  }
  /*----------Dropdown ends-----------*/
```

```html
 <div id="DivMenu">
    <div class="Menu"><a style="text-decoration:none;"  href="index.html">HomePage</a></div>

    <div class="Menu"><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="About.html">About</a></div>

    <div class="Menu"><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="Survey.html">Take our survey  </a></div>

    <div class="Menu">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Login/Register</a>
            <ul>
                <div>
                    <li class="liwidth">
                        <a class="linkvalign" href="Login.html">Login</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="liwidth" >
                        <a class="linkvalign" href="Register.html">Register</a>
                    </li>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can see that the thing causing the problem is the `<li>`'s in the 4th div, but I can't figure out how to arrange it so that it doesn't overflow.

I've tried removing the `<li>` tags altogether but that just causes more issues.

Comment: Sorry, tried to recreate but unfortunately couldn't understand your issue. Would you like to post a biggg image of what is happening and what you want it to happen?

Comment: @PraveenKumar https://imgur.com/a/gN6PB The first image is maximized, where there is no overflow.The 2nd is a smaller window which makes the page horizontally scroll and cause overflow

Comment: @Repub619 Is this a sidebar or a navbar? I see the elements are stacked one above another, usually a navbar the elements are horizontal to each other!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure I understand what you're trying to do, and therefore what the proper solution should be, but adding `overflow: hidden` to `.Main` will prevent its content from overflowing at least.

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear, I took a screenshot of my problem: https://imgur.com/a/gN6PB The first image is the window maximized, and the second is it in a smaller window where the 4th div is overflowing and causing a horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: And `overflow: hidden` does not fix that?